# How do laser printers produce the positive and negative charges on the paper?

Tags: charge, electron

I understand the general idea of how it works but I am a little confused on the actual details.

For instance I understand that the corona wire positively charges the entire drum and the laser then uncharges or negatively charges the parts of the drum where the text is.

My question is, how specifically does it do that? Is there something special about the composition of the corona wire or the current running through it that shoots off positive charges to the drum?

How does the laser actually discharge or apply negative charge to the drum areas?

How do the toner particles get charged?

Comment: You missed the most obvious aspect of the question, ... What is the drum made from?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magic about the electron beam, the corona wire, the drum, or the paper. The "magic" is in the coating on the outside of the drum.  It is a special sandwich of materials which are photo-sensitive to the image from the original paper, from microfilm, from a scanned laser beam, or from an array of LEDs.  The combination of charging, exposing, and then transfering to paper is how Xerography works.

All the high-voltage charges have a positive and negative end. The drum is connected to the positive side of the charge, and the toner powder container is connected to the negative side of the charge. So toner is attracted to stick to the drum. When light is focused on the drum it causes that part to lose its charge, so the toner falls off into the waste bin.

As the copy paper goes near the drum, there is a positively-charged wire under the paper which attracts the remaining (black) toner powder away from the drum and onto the paper.  Then the paper goes through the very hot fuser to melt the plastic toner dust into the surface of the copy paper.

[image: Diagram of Xerography]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes sense for the drum but where I am confused is how do other objects obtain a charge. For instance, how does the toner obtain a negative charge? Or for powder coating, how does the metal object obtain a negative charge and the powder color obtain a positive charge?

Comment: I added more detail about the charging and transfer process.