# Will the laser beam of a laser printer make the OPC drum more positively charged or more negatively charged

Tags: charge, laser

while I was tutoring students about A LEVEL computer science in chapter 3 -- hardware, I found a very interesting question about printer.
Some websites say that the laser beam could remove charges on the toner which makes the area exposed to the laser more **negatively charged**, like the following websites:
https://cosmosmagazine.com/technology/how-does-a-laser-printer-work/
[How do laser printers produce the positive and negative charges on the paper?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235082/how-do-laser-printers-produce-the-positive-and-negative-charges-on-the-paper)

While on the other hand, some say that the laser beam would make the area exposed to the laser more **positively charged**, like the following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB0HnXcW8qQ
https://www.tonerbuzz.com/blog/the-laser-printing-process/

I am not sure if they are just using different technologies or is the one way of saying this is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: This question is a better fit for the Physics site. https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OPC stands for "Organic Photo Conductor". The coating dissipates charge (to the metal drum) where light hits it.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235082/how-do-laser-printers-produce-the-positive-and-negative-charges-on-the-paper which gives a detailed answer.

Comment: @colintd, Thank you for your reply. I read that one already before posting, and it is included as a hyperlink in the first paragraph, it did a perfect explanation on why the laser beam could remove charges on the toner which makes the area exposed to the laser more negatively charged, however, it did not say anything about the second situation, that's why I posted here.

Comment: I've reread all the links, and there is a significant lack of precision when they discuss the charging polarity and the image.  My understanding is that the drum is almost always positive and the toner negative.  Where the laser shines the drum conducts and the charge leaks away.  Therefore the laser scans a negative onto the drum.  It is done this way because the original optical copies just used a focused image of the brightly lit original, and you needed the white "light" areas not to attract toner, and the dark layers to attract toner.